analytically continue functions on independent planes in $\Bbb R^3$
I know techniques to analytically continue some functions off the positive real line. I am less sure given I have 2 independent euclidean planes sitting in $\Bbb R^3$ with some function $f$ defined on the positive real lines of the respective planes.
For ex. I can continue $f$ on each plane independently, i.e. on the $x$-$y$ space and $y$-$z$. This gives rise to functions, now complex valued. But I am confused if this can even occur.

Am I allowed to analytically continue functions on the $y$-$z$ plane as sitting in $\Bbb R^3$?

I'm simply used to just using analytic continuation for the standard real line.
